# Paramagnetic material exactly midway between two strong magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Let's say we have a paramagnetic material. Now - like in the illustration below - place two **identical very strong** magnets **fixed in place** opposing each other and place the material exactly midway where the magnetic flux is a horizontal arrow from North to South.

> S (Magnet 1) N | -------- material -------- | S (Magnet 2) N

What will happen to the material? Which direction will it go or will it stay still or is it 50%/50% chance or is it indeterminate?

Here, I am neglecting any external effects such as the earth's magnetic field.

Comment: It the arrangement of the magnets that you have shown, the magnets are attracting to each other. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Thanks. What I meant is for them to be fixed so they do not move. I updated the question.

Comment: From symmetry I would expect no motion